# Make letter after apostrophe small with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to turn this text:

> She’S Saying It’S Time To 'Find A Solution'

into this text:

> She’s Saying It’s Time To 'Find A Solution'

only using Javascript.

I tried using:

```
str.replace(/'S /,"'s ");
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas? Please not that the whitespace after the S is an important heuristic.

Comment: it just tried that in the console: `"She'S Saying It'S Time To 'Find A Solution'".replace( /'S /g, "'s " )`, you were missing the 'global' modificator.

Comment: I've added the 'global' modificator but it still doesn't work. By the way: I found out the problem lies with /'S / and not with "'s "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem (none of the solutions below solved it...)

The problem was that my string was using a **different type of single quote** (’ instead of '). The replace function above only recognizes the second type of single quote...

SOLUTION: with a simple amendment, both single quotes can be replaced:

```
str.replace(/’S |'S /g,"'s ");
```

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace the whole string, you must add the global modifier as so

```
var str = "She'S Saying It'S Time To 'Find A Solution'";

alert(str.replace(/'S\s/g, "'s "))
```

Comment: I found the problem: I've been testing all sorts of things and I found out that the single quote on my page is a different sort of single quote. ’ instead of ' - what is this all about?

Answer (score 2):

No reason why that wouldn't work. Are you sure you're doing `str = str.replace(....);`? Otherwise you're just calculating the result and throwing it away.

Comment: yes I'm doing it properly. In fact I tested it with another pattern (Replaced "She" with "Janet") and it works